# getting values from tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec

Tags: python, tensorflow

The returned EstimatorSpec Object is iterable when the PREDICT ModeKey is passed to tf.estimator.Estimator.

```
predictions = { 'class_ids': tf.argmax(input=logits, axis=1), 'logits': logits }
if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
  return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, predictions=predictions)
```

then,

```
prediction_results = classifier.predict(input_fn=prediction_dataset_input)
for x, each in enumerate(prediction_results):
    print(each)
```

produces a line for each of the predictions like this;

```
....
{'class_ids': 1, 'logits': array([-32976400., -30171870.], dtype=float32)}
{'class_ids': 1, 'logits': array([-32958380., -30386898.], dtype=float32)}
{'class_ids': 1, 'logits': array([-32940332., -30601930.], dtype=float32)}
{'class_ids': 1, 'logits': array([-32922300., -30816956.], dtype=float32)}
....
```

How could I get the TRAIN ModeKey to return something that is iterable? Ideally, I would like to print each feature value used and the computed logit at defined steps in the training. I am returning;

```
if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
            mode,
            loss=loss,
            predictions=predictions,
        train_op=train_objective)
```

then,

```
prediction_results = classifier.train(input_fn=lambda: dataset_input_fn(
                file_dataset_feed,
                perform_shuffle=True,
                repeat_count=100))
for x, each in enumerate(prediction_results):
    print(each)
```

produces;

```
TypeError: 'Estimator' object is not iterable
```